# Uploading a File via FTP using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, webclient

I am writing a Powershell script that watches a directory, and when a file (or multiple) is uploaded into the directory, it takes those files, copies them to another folder, sends them to an FTP server, and then deletes the file from the original directory.

I am having problems connecting to the FTP server. I am not sure if the problem is the way I am configuring the Web Client, or if the problem is that the ftp URI has spaces in it and I am not escaping them properly.

Here is the code:

```html
$source = "c:/testFtp"

$ftpdestination = "ftp://username:password@ftp.ftpsite.com/folder with space/folder with space"

$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient

$files = Get-ChildItem $source
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Uploading $file"
    try {
        $ftp = "$ftpdestination/$file"
        $uri = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftp

        $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $source/$file)

    } catch {
        Add-content "$logs" -value "There was an error uploading to ftp"
    }
}
$webclient.Dispose()
```

I have tried escaping the folder spaces multiple ways, so I am beginning to think that is not the problem and that I am not configuring the web client properly.

It is also not catching errors very often, so I don't believe it throws an error when the webclient has failure on the upload. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what errors do you get exactly?

Comment: Have you defined `$logs` anywhere?

Comment: This is just a snippet, the logs is defined and I still get errors occasionally if the path is completely wrong @Theo

Comment: I do not get errors, that is part of the problem. I run it, but the files do not show up on the ftp site. I am wondering if it is a problem on the FTP server side @marsze

Answer (score -1):

**ANSWER:**

It turns out the WebClient was connecting properly, but SSL was blocking the files from being sent. I found this out by using C# to compile and run the script, and it gave me better error handling, as I am new to Powershell scripts and cannot seem to get good error handling.

After researching, I could not find a way to enable SSL with WebClient, so I switched over to FtpWebRequest. Here is the successful code (This try catch block does not seem to log errors as I would like, but the tool will successfully send files to the ftp server now:

```html
try {
    $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$ftpsite/$filename")
    $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp
    $ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
    $ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$username","$password")
    $ftp.UseBinary = $true
    $ftp.UsePassive = $true
    $ftp.EnableSSL = $true  #<-----------------This was the line that made this work
    $ftp.KeepAlive = $false
    # read in the file to upload as a byte array
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$source/$file")
    $ftp.ContentLength = $content.Length
    # get the request stream, and write the bytes into it
    $rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
    $rs.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)
    # be sure to clean up after ourselves
    $rs.Close()
    $rs.Dispose()

    Write-Host "Successfully uploaded: $source/$file"
    Copy-Item "$source/$file" -Destination "$copydestination"
    Remove-Item "$source/$file"
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), Added File: $file to $copydestination"
    Add-content "$logs" -value $logline 
    } catch {
        $res = $ftp.GetResponse()
        Add-content "$logs" -value "There was an error: $res.StatusCode" 
        Write-Error -Message "There was an error." -ErrorAction Stop
    }
```